# Вычислить сумму разных чисел в массиве

Tags: swift

Решаю похожие задачи для отбора на стажировку в Яндекс, вроде решил задачу, но выдает WA (Wrong Answer)

Условия: 
1. Сумма различных

Ограничение времени 2 секунды

Ограничение памяти  256Mb

Ввод    стандартный ввод или input.txt

Вывод   стандартный вывод или output.txt

Отправить на проверку нужно исходный код программы, решающей поставленную задачу.

Дан массив a из n целых чисел. Напишите программу, которая выведет сумму различных чисел в массиве.

Формат ввода

В первой строке входных данных записано число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100 000). Во второй строке записаны n целых чисел ai (0 ≤ ai ≤ 1 000 000 000).

Формат вывода

Выведите единственное число s, сумму различных чисел в массиве a. Будьте внимательны в выборе используемого целочисленного типа данных.

Пример 1

Ввод
3

3 5 4

Вывод

12

---

Пример 2

Ввод
5

5 5 5 5 5

Вывод

5

---

Пример 3

Ввод
10

7 10 3 2 7 4 8 5 9 10

Вывод

48

---

Мой код:

```
import Foundation

var arrayCount: Int? = Int(readLine() ?? "0")


var arrayOfElements: [Int] = []

for _ in 0...(arrayCount ?? 0) {
    let element: Int? = Int(readLine() ?? "")

    arrayOfElements.append(element ?? 0)

}

var setOfElements: Set = Set(arrayOfElements)

print(setOfElements.reduce(0, +))
```

Comment: У вас основная ошибка в том что вы читаете элементы не из одной строки а каждый элемент из новой строки. Вдобавок у вас цикл от 0 до количества элементов и вы читаете на 1 больше элементов чем нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Решение

---

```
import Foundation

let countOfElementsInArray: String? = readLine() // Записываю количество элементов в следующий строке

let sringWithElements: String? = readLine()  // Сама строка с элементами

let outputValue = Set(sringWithElements!.split(separator: " ")).compactMap( { Int($0) } ).reduce(0, +)

print(outputValue)
```

По времени получилось: 201ms

---

По памяти получилось: 29.13Mb

---

Спасибо за помощь - Виктор Мишустин, MBo, VAndrJ.

Comment: Извините, вы поблагодарили авторов других ответов, но ни один из ответов не приняли как правильный. Они действительно не помогли с решением?

Comment: Помогли, их код не проходил тесты, но логика решения была правильная, я код чуть-чуть причесал, тесты он прошел, поэтому и поблагодарил, но не отметил их ответы, как правильные.

Answer (score 2):

Глядя на условие задачи и примеры ввода/вывода создается впечатление, что задачу скопировали из какого-то задачника для C и не потрудились адаптировать под Swift. Поэтому опираемся на примеры.

Первое замечание - игнорируем n(количество элементов массива, так как оно не дано), а введенные числа являются строкой.

Второе - игнорируем неправильный ввод. Поэтому введенный массив прочитаем так:

```
let inputArray = readLine()!.split(separator: " ").compactMap({ Int($0) })
```

Ну и полное, простое решение будет:

```
let outputValue: Int = Set(readLine()!.split(separator: " ").compactMap({ Int($0) })).reduce(0, +)
```

Наиболее узкое по памяти место здесь:

```
.split(separator: " ").compactMap({ Int($0) })
```

Если не проходит по памяти - нужно сначала оптимизировать здесь, далее смотреть какие могут быть проблемы по входным данным.

Comment: Количество элементов дано в условии.

Comment: @Son'kaV, в отредактированном вопросе действительно теперь есть. До этого, когда отвечал, было по 1 строчке на каждый пример :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать решить через индексацию элементов, решается через 3 прохода но в целом скорость O(n), единственное не знаю хватит ли памяти. Но можете попробовать.

```
func doubleSum(baseArray: [Int]) -> Int {
  let max = baseArray.max()!
  var ks = Array(repeating: 0, count: max + 1)
  baseArray.forEach { element in ks[element] += 1 }
  var result = 0
  for index in baseArray.indices {
    if ks[baseArray[index]] > 0 {
      result += baseArray[index]
      ks[baseArray[index]] = 0
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ограничения `0 ≤ ai ≤ 1 000 000 000` и `Ограничение памяти 256Mb` говорят нам, что можно уложиться в лимит памяти, используя простейший словарь - массив байтов или целых чисел, в котором наличие каждого значения соответствует одному **биту**, на это уйдёт 128 мегабайт. Использование полноценного словаря будет медленнее.

При этом входные данные необязательно куда-то складывать, если есть возможность читать одно входное значение за другим (хотя и чтение в массив предварительно заданной длины должно быть достаточно быстрым)

Результат должен быть 64-разрядным, т.е. в 32-битной системе ответ в Int не влезет.

Псевдокод:

```
bits = array[128000000] of Byte
для каждого значения value:
      addr = value / 8     
      mask = 1 << (value % 8)    
      if (bits[addr] && mask) == 0: //если бит ещё не установлен
            sum += value
            bits[addr]  |=  mask     //установить его
```